# Perfect closure is perfect

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've been self-studying inseparable extensions and there's something that seems obvious to everybody but not to me. Let's clear out some definitions that are not so universal:

> Let $K$ be a field and $f\in K[X]$ a polynomial. We say it is *separable* if all its roots are distinct over its splitting field. We say it is *purely inseparable* if it has only one root over its splitting field, and this root is multiple.
>
> A field extension $F\subset K$ is *purely inseparable* (resp. *separable*) if every element of $K$ is the root of a purely inseparable (resp. *separable) polynomial in $F[X]$.
>
> A field K is *perfect* if every irreducible polynomial over K is separable.
>
> Let $F\subset K$ be a field extension of characteristic $p$. The *perfect closure*, or *purely inseparable closure* of $F$ in $K$ is the greatest intermediate field that is purely inseparable over $F$. We will denote it by $K^p_F$

We can prove that $K^p_F$ consists of all the elements $\alpha\in K$ such that there is $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha^{p^n}\in F$.

Another property that may be useful is that an irreducible polynomial over a field of characteristic $p$ splits on its splitting field like this: $$f(X)= a_0(X-a_1)^{p^n} \dots (X-a_r)^{p^n}$$ where the $a_1,\dots,a_r$ are pairwise distinct.

Now, why is it true that $K^p_F$ is a perfect field? Please try to prove it only using these definitions and properties.

EDIT: I have also proved that

> A field is perfect iff every finite extension is separable, iff every algebraic 
>   extension is separable.

which may come in handy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your question is, that it isn't necessarily true that $K_F^p$ is a perfect field. For example, let $F$ be any non-perfect field (e.g. $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$), and let $K=F$, so that we must have $K_F^p=F$.

When $K=\bar{F}$, an algebraic closure of $F$, then $K_F^p$ is the smallest perfect subfield of $K$ containing $F$, hence the name "perfect closure". This is [Lemma 3.16 in Karpilovsky's *Field Theory*](http://books.google.com/books?id=QqFIvW85Yt0C&lpg=PP1&ots=gLugeC1e2Z&dq=karpilovsky%20field%20theory&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false) (for some reason I couldn't find this in a more standard reference like Lang). As you mention, $K_F^p$ consists of those $\alpha\in K$ such that $\alpha^{p^n}\in F$ for some $n$, and note that the field that Karpilovsky refers to as the perfect closure is
$$F^{p^{-\infty}}=\{a\in\bar{F}\mid a^{p^n}\in F \text{ for some }n\geq0\}.$$

Comment: Why is it true that "all subextensions $L/F_p$ of $\bar{F}/F_p$ are separable"?

Comment: @Bruno: I have edited.

Comment: @Zev: Sadly, I can't find the book you mention...

Comment: @Bruno: I have also found a reference for the above proposition [in Bourbaki](http://books.google.com/books?id=bDLecF34d8UC&lpg=PA111&dq=%22perfect%20closure%22&pg=PA112#v=onepage&q=%22perfect%20closure%22&f=false) (Prop 3 in the link). It is stated in more generality (it works for all rings of characteristic $p$).

Comment: Oh, but I found it as lemma 2.24 in Karpilovsky's "Topics in Field Theory" which is, ahem, findable on the web. It is quite clear there. Thank you.